# Does the antiderivative of an indicator function?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I have an indicator function of the form $I\{a<t<b\}$ and I need the antiderivative of it with respect to $t$.

I believe I can't use the fundamental theorem of calculus to simply write it as $\int_0^t I\{a<s<b\} ds$ (which would be very convenient) since it's not a continuous function.

It's not clear to me whether such a function even exists or how I would write it.

Answer (score 1):

For $t\in(a,b)$ we have $I(t)=1$, so the antiderivative, say $F$, would be $F(x)=x+C_1$. For $x>b$ it would be $F(x)=C_2$ and for $x<a$, $F(x)=C_3$. It is impossible to find $C_1, C_2, C_3$ to make $F$ a differentiable function on the whole $\Bbb R$, or on any interval containing properly $(a,b)$.

Answer (score 0):

There does not exists a function $f$ defined on an open interval properly containing $(a,b)$ and such that $f'(x)=I\{a<x<b\}(x)$. The reason is that [derivatives have the intermediate value property,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) but the indicator function doesn't.

Comment: Nevertheless the right hand side is not a differentiable function. Any antiderivative is differentiable. So, your "equation" is not true. The situation changes if you want to compute a definite integral.

Comment: I need the antiderivative, not the definite integral.

Comment: That is why my comment. In fact, what was written above, is the distribution function (multiplied by $b-a$) of the uniform distribution on $(a,b)$, so this is in fact a definite integral.

Comment: Yeah I was commenting at the poster, not you  :).

Comment: @Patty OK, hint taken :)